# I could not detect my device when i type "adb devices" in CMD (in windows 8.1)

Tags: android, google-chrome, usb

I installed google USB drivers but couldn't find my any device under heading "list of devices".

List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

then later 
D:\pushnotif>adb devices
List of devices attached

how can i make my device detect for debugging?

Comment: Did you enable debugging on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at your phone rather than at your computer.You should enable debugging mode on your phone... Have a look at this: http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/

Answer (score 0):

You should install usb drivers for your device on Windows, if you don't have nexus device or cyanogenmodOS. Then activate debug mode, then when you plug device in PC, choose on status bar connection mode(for Sony - "only charge", for LG - MTP mode, for some HTC devices - PTP), then check it. It helped me, i have 3 devices for connect to Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ya install adb drivers from the below link for windows 8.1
https://androidmtk.com/download-universal-adb-driver

If it doesn't happen, it will show some instructions just follow it, you'l be able to do it